# Gatling feeder through the iteration over a map

Tags: scala, gatling

I wish to create a custom feeder in Gatling scala, which fills the parameter element via iterating through a map.
I have the following code snippet:

```
val idPostFeeder = Iterator.continually(
    Map("postId" -> getValues())
)
```

`getValues` is a Collection containing String elements

I tried also the following way:

```
val idPostFeeder = (for (i <- getFile().get(l.get(b)) yield {
    Map("postId" -> s"$i")
} )

val l = getFile().keysIterator.toList;

var b = l.indexOf() until l.indexOf(mapLenght)
```

`getFile` is a `Map[String, String]`, from which I need the values passed to the feeder.

Is there a way to fill a feeder via an iteration over a Collection or a Map?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

for a collection of Strings, you just need to convert to a Map

```
getValues.map(s => Map("postId" -> s)).toIterator
```

you now have an iterator that maps "postId" to each value of your collection